# How can I get my button and text to fill the column regardless of screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This has been driving me crazy. I want two side-by-side columns to work like so:

```
[Button] [Long text description]       [Button] [Long text description]
```

I'd like the buttons to be the same width, and the text to not bleed into the column to the right. I tried to implement this like so:

```css
multicol {
  display: inline-block;
  column-count:2;
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
 
}
```

```html
  <!-- Imagine 20-25 of these in a row -->
  <div class='container-fluid multicol'>
     <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-xs-5'>
              <button class='btn btn-block'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
          </div>
          <div class='col-xs-7'>
               <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

But my buttons start resizing on different screen resolutions, and they are not always the same size. How can I make sure the buttons have the same width (the entire column) *at all times, regardless of screen resolution?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`container-fluid` is set to the width of the entire browser, and so the `col-xs-5` element will always vary, as it will be a percentage of the browser width. `btn-block` will ensure that the button is 100% of the variable `col-xs-5` width.

If you want the button element to be a set width regardless of screen resolution, I suggest giving the button element an explicit width,

e.g.

```
button {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Long button text will likely break to a second line, but the button width will remain consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve something like this:

```css
.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Imagine 20-25 of these in a row -->
  <div>
     <div class="col">
         <button>One</button>
         <span>Description one</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col">
         <button>One</button>
         <span>Description one</span>
     </div>
     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a unit in CSS relative to viewport. You can use `vw` for viewport width and `vh` for viewport height.

Example, if you want to have an element with width same as the viewport, then style the element like this:

```
element {
    width: 100vw;
}
```